# How to set schema location for @ManyToMany Entity Collection with JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I want to create 2 tables in my PostgreSQL database while using the Spring-boot JPA.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "test")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

And my `User` class

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "test")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String group_id;
    private String email;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The 2 tables above are created in `test` schema but the `user_roles` is trying to be created without any schema selected and I get the error

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in`

So my question is: How to assign the schema to the `user_roles` table that JPA is trying to create